# How to catch RelativeLayout pressed state in Android?

Tags: android, state, android-relativelayout, pressed

I have Relative Layout with two TextViews inside.
How I can change text color TextViews, when RelativeLayout is pressed?

I tried used selectors, but Relative Layout don't support text color attribute.

Also a tried catch Relative Layout pressed state with OnFocus and OnTouch Listeners, but they don't working(OnFocusChangeListener) or working in one side(OnTouchListener).

The code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="243dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/singup_button_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/sungup"
        android:textColor="@drawable/singup_button_text_selector"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/singupTV1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/singup"
            android:textColor="#3c5775"/>




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/singupTV2"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/singupTV1"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/singup_extended"
            android:textColor="#506378"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an onClickListener on the RelativeLayout, then in the onClick method, change the text colors in both TextViews in your code.

Comment: Not a way, because it's working only after releasing the finger.

Comment: Its must begin from finger touch and stop when I release the finger.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was setting an `OnTouchListener`.

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            // focus in
        } else{
            // focus out
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```